# UV Triangulation Issue

Tags: uv, topology

I'm trying to model a tower for a castle with shingles that wrap around it evenly. I keep encountering a problem where the faces of my unwrapped mesh will triangulate themselves and cause unwanted warping in my textures. Example:

Before scaling
[image]

Afer scaling
[image]

I've tried adding a triangulation modifier, but that only reverses the direction of the warping. Does anybody have a workaround for this? I would deeply appreciate any help or explanation!

Comment: is your grid supposed to keep the same scale or is it supposed to scale down?

Answer (score 0):

The why [is given here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194946/simple-undivided-plane-uv-map-not-behaving-as-expected).

Workarounds:

- If you want to keep the grid at the same size:

Use the option "*correct face attribute"*.

[image]

- If you want to stretch down the grid when scaling down:

Use some subdivisions to compensate the triangle effect. Only vertical subdivisions are needed, so you can also give some loop cuts manually.

[image]